Short story about a paralyzed astronaut on a tiny planet with tiny aliens
I'm looking for this short story, unknown time period.
An astronaut on a tiny planet somehow cannot move (crashed and paralysed?).
Gets conscious, hears tiny beings. Helps them find his food and shares his carrots. Tells them about science; they develop agriculture and start producing more food. After that, small beings build a tower to hang the astronaut's mirror on it so he can see their fields and other structures they build guided by him. Fast-forward a couple of decades; the astronaut is dead; humans find a tiny planet with advanced civilisation with tall buildings and beautiful spires.
I believe the story and its author are quite famous, but I still cannot find it.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Alan Dean Foster - Gift Of A Useless Man
sorry, you can close the question

@IvanBorsuk Done!

@IvanBorsuk: Nothing wrong with finding your own answer. :) No real issue in posting it as an answer, at that. But congrats on finding it!
